# Is it possible in Flutter to iterate a row of widgets with properties with a for loop?

Tags: function, for-loop, flutter, dart, containers

I am trying to make a dynamic widget that produces containers with editable properties (color, title, etc) based on an inputted number into a function or for loop. I.e. I type a "4" and I get a row of four containers that I can edit their colors, titles, and whatever other property I specify.

Container I am trying to produce based on the number typed into the function or for loop:

```
class RectButton extends StatelessWidget {
  RectButton({this.buttonChild, this.bgColor, this.onPress});

  final Widget buttonChild;
  final Color bgColor;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 100, height: 50),
        child: Center(child: buttonChild),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: bgColor,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right you're looking for creating a list of widgets dynamically.

Yes, it's doable when you have the data to create a widget out of it.

Let's say you have a list of strings

```dart
List<String> strings = ['Str1', 'Str2', 'Str3'];
```

And you want to make a list of `Text` widget out of them, you can use `map`.

```dart
strings.map((str)=> Text(str));
```

You can assign it to a `Row` like this:

```dart
Row(
    children: strings.map((str)=> Text(str)).toList()
)
```

For your widget, I did this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Home(),
    ),
  ));
}

class RectButton extends StatelessWidget {
  RectButton({this.buttonChild, this.bgColor, this.onPress});
  final Widget buttonChild;
  final Color bgColor;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 100, height: 50),
        child: Center(child: buttonChild),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: bgColor,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: List.generate(
        4,
        (index) => RectButton(
          bgColor: Colors.red[100 + 100 * index],
          buttonChild: Text('Button $index'),
          onPress: () {
            print('Button $index is pressed!');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is getting on the right track- so thanks for your help! I was hoping when I called the widget, I could dynamically adjust the number of RectButtons that would be created and be able to individually customize them with different names like "Login", "Register", "Settings", and "Help". I am mainly curious if this is possible because the app I am designing reuses the RectButton in a variety of screens with varying numbers of RectButton in rows (i.e. 4 on screen 1, 3 of screen 3, 2 on screen 2, etc)

Comment: Yes it can be done, as I said before if the data is stored in a way that you can use a loop/map to build each widget you can do it like the `string/Text`, if not you have to make each of them individually and then pass them to screens or other widgets.